# `Login failed for user ''` when executing report with dynamic data source and unattended execution account

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

For version 14.0.600.689 I've setup unattended account, data source based on parameter and Credentials option "Do not use credentials". It works fine.

Than on another server we've upgraded to latest 14.0.600.744. And same configuration gives an error:

> ### Login failed for user ''.
>
> Cannot create a connection to data source 'MainDataSource'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)

When we setup secured credential for report inside it works.

Did something changed in logic of using unattended execution account?

Do I have any other way to setup one credential for expression based data source for many reports?

Answer (score 0):

So looks like this is a bug, between 14.0.600.689 and 14.0.600.744.

But I found a workaround, in newer version when you add in the end of dynamic connection string an option of "Integrated Security=true" it will use unattended execution account, otherwise it wraps with User ID empty and give that SqlConnection error.

While in older version, it will use unattended execution account always with an option "Do not use credentials".